# How do I find postgresql queries that do not use an index

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-performance

We have a postgresql database that is slow in production. During development it is quick since we have much less data in the database.

I would like to get a log of the queries that can be expected to be slow in production even though they are fast during development.

**How can I find the sql queries that do not use an index but instead do a table scan?**

And btw would this make sense to do?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.  You have to execute EXPLAIN PLAN on every query you find in your application.  Compare the WHERE clauses to indexes on the tables they access.

Comment: Who designed the database model, the application programmers?

Comment: You say "queries that can be expected to be slow in production", "queries that do not use an index but instead do a table scan" and "During development it is quick since we have much less data in the database". Note that the planner will switch plans based on the amount of data (and more, such as cardinality), so you can't infer the plan that will be used in production (with a large dataset) from that which will be used in development (with a small dataset). Your best bet it to copy (or simulate) the production dataset in development, or you'll have to check plans in production.

Comment: Also, not all seq scans are bad. A seq scan on a small table (e.g. a list of states) is perfectly normal and often a better solution than an index scan.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html

1. set `auto_explain.log_min_duration` to whatever number of milliseconds that you consider to be "slow".
2. run grep "Seq Scan" WHATEVER_YOUR_LOG_DIRECTORY_IS (can check with `show log_directory`)